# If I insert group by in the query my search bar does not work anymore

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hi all I have implemented a query that adjusts my search bar:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM clienti
INNER JOIN campagne_cliente
ON campagne_cliente.cliente_id_campagna = clienti.cliente_id
INNER JOIN campagne
ON campagne.id_campagna = campagne_cliente.id_campagna_cliente  " . $queryCondition;
$result = mysqli_query($connessione,$sql);
```

but in this way it is not functional for me, as it replicates "n" times the presence of a "campagne.id_campagna".

and I would need a query that used the group by, in this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM clienti
INNER JOIN campagne_cliente
ON campagne_cliente.cliente_id_campagna = clienti.cliente_id
INNER JOIN campagne
ON campagne.id_campagna = campagne_cliente.id_campagna_cliente GROUP BY campagne.id_campagna " . $queryCondition;
$result = mysqli_query($connessione,$sql);
```

only that I know perfectly that as a parameter it's not accepted, but in this way only at the visual level for me it would be correct since I do not have to display the same name for how many products, but only once the name of the client, for how many campaigns does .

How can I use group by to allow my search bar to work correctly?

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved?

Comment: @jarlh because I need to make the owner's name appear on video only once, not as many times as many products do and therefore I need a group by

Comment: then select the distinct owners name or if its sql server use partition

Comment: But an owner can have several rows, with different values for the other columns - you need to specify which values to chose. Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: If a query has no aggregating functions then a group by clause is superfluous

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran exactly, basically I need the name of the owner who owns an advertising campaign to be visualized only once, without the group by being replicated as many times as many products

Comment: then you can remove the group by clause and have select distinct owner instead of select *

Comment: @jarlh of course you, a landlord own more advertising campaign but obviously these campaigns will have different ids, my difficulty that without using the group by, I find that for the same campagne.id_campagna is reproduced the owner's name as many times as many products

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran and how should the query be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT OWNER
FROM clienti 
INNER JOIN campagne_cliente
ON campagne_cliente.cliente_id_campagna = clienti.cliente_id
INNER JOIN campagne
ON campagne.id_campagna = campagne_cliente.id_campagna_cliente  " . $queryCondition;
$result = mysqli_query($connessione,$sql);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for spending time for me

Answer (score 0):

Does this do it?

```
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(*)
FROM clienti
WHERE
EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM campagne_cliente 
INNER JOIN campagne ON campagne.id_campagna = campagne_cliente.id_campagna_cliente
WHERE campagne_cliente.cliente_id_campagna = clienti.cliente_id)" 
. $queryCondition;
$result = mysqli_query($connessione,$sql);
```

Tell me if it helped you.

Comment: it does not work, because in this way I have on the video the owner's name as many times as many products